# Pull data from a webpage to use

Tags: php, python, html

To give some background, I sell Lego parts online. The order total when you place the order is based on the price of the parts you purchased, and the shipping costs.

Shipping costs vary depending on the weight of the order, and the country of shipment.

I am not a techie buff, and thats why I need some help. I know the basics, but not much else, though I'd love to learn and I've been trying around with this for days before coming here.

The source code of an order page, the only place where you can see the weight is this:

```
<FONT CLASS="fv">Estimated Weight of Order:</FONT></TD><TD ALIGN="RIGHT"><FONT CLASS="fv">2.17oz&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;61.44g</FONT>
```

It is the same for every single order.

So, I know where the data I want is.

What I need help with is, coding something that pulls the data out of this webpage (say it's inside a webpage called order.com/order.asp and the document contains a bunch of other data apart from the weight) and exporting a shipping price based on the weight it inputed. I don't know whether you can do this with PHP or Python, etc.

I would have on my server a... say a table with the shipping costs based on weight. Now, what I needed, would be to take that bit of data from the order.com website into my own server. (On my own server process the weight data that I took, match it with the shipping cost, pull out invoices, etc). The weight data is in the order page, always on a line like the one I posted on the question. I just read about web scraping. Maybe some PHP that looks into the order page till it finds the line with the weight, and pulls out the weight?

Many, many, many thanks for your help, and I apologize in advance if I sound too uninformed, which I am. I really need a detailed explanation.

Gerald

**TL;DR**Two webpages. One is in my server and one isn't. The one that isn't in my server (order.asp), has this line:

```
<FONT CLASS="fv">Estimated Weight of Order:</FONT></TD><TD ALIGN="RIGHT"><FONT CLASS="fv">XX.XXoz&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;XX.XXg</FONT>
```

I need something that I can put in my server, queries the weight from the page that isn't on my server (order.asp page) and matches the weight with a shipping price that I would have on my page (as a table or maybe with ifs).

There will be different order pages (order1.asp order2.asp order3.asp) with different weights. The script or whatever should do that for ea. wpage.

Thanks.

---

This would be the source code of an example page that I would need to take the weight of. Removed some sensitive info.

```
<SCRIPT TYPE="text/javascript" LANGUAGE="JavaScript">



function killImage(imgName){

   if (document.images){

    document.images[imgName].src="/images/noImage.gif"

   }

}



function killImageM(imgName){

   if (document.images){

    document.images[imgName].src="/images/noImageM.gif"

   }

}



</SCRIPT>

<HTML>

<HEAD>

 <META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" CONTENT="text/html; charset=utf-8">

 <META HTTP-EQUIV="IMAGETOOLBAR" CONTENT="NO">

 <LINK REL="STYLESHEET" TYPE="text/css" HREF="/stylesheet.css?13">

 <STYLE TYPE="text/css">body { margin: 15 auto; }</STYLE>

 <SCRIPT TYPE="text/javascript" LANGUAGE="javascript" SRC="/js/getAjax.js"></SCRIPT>

 <SCRIPT TYPE="text/javascript" LANGUAGE="javascript" SRC="/lytebox/lytebox.js?10"></SCRIPT>

 <LINK REL="STYLESHEET" HREF="/lytebox/lytebox.css?13" TYPE="text/css" MEDIA="screen" />

</HEAD>

<BODY BGCOLOR="#666666">

<CENTER>

<TABLE WIDTH="680" CELLPADDING="10" CELLSPACING="0"><TR><TD BGCOLOR="#FFFFFF">

<TABLE BORDER="0" CELLPADDING="0" CELLSPACING="0"><TR>

 <TD><A HREF="/index.asp"><IMG SRC="/images/logowhite.gif" WIDTH="200" HEIGHT="60" ALIGN="ABSMIDDLE" BORDER="0"></A>&nbsp;</TD>

 <TD> <FONT SIZE="+3">Order #3953198</FONT></TD></TR></TABLE><P><FONT FACE="Tahoma,Arial" SIZE="2">

<HR NOSHADE SIZE="1" COLOR="#000000"><B>Order Summary</B><HR NOSHADE SIZE="1" COLOR="#000000">



<TABLE WIDTH="100%" CELLPADDING="5" CELLSPACING="0" BORDER="0" BGCOLOR="#EEEEEE"><TR><TD WIDTH="60%" VALIGN="TOP">

<TABLE WIDTH="100%" BORDER="0" CELLPADDING="1" CELLSPACING="0" CLASS="ta">

 <TR>

  <TD WIDTH="125">Order Date:</TD>

  <TD>Nov 20, 2013 17:12</TD>

 </TR>



 <TR>

  <TD>Payment By:</TD>

  <TD>PayPal.com</TD>

 </TR>



 <TR>

  <TD>Payment In:</TD>

  <TD>Euro</TD>

 </TR>



 <TR VALIGN="TOP">

  <TD>Order Status:</TD>

  <TD>Shipped</TD>

 </TR>

 <TR>

  <TD>Changed:</TD>

  <TD>Nov 22, 2013 14:15</TD>

 </TR>

 <TR>

  <TD NOWRAP>Total Items:</TD>

  <TD>24</TD>

 </TR>

 <TR>

  <TD NOWRAP>Unique Items (Lots):</TD>

  <TD>2</TD>

 </TR>

 <TR>

  <TD NOWRAP>Invoiced:</TD>

  <TD>Nov 21, 2013 08:56</TD>

 </TR>



  <TR VALIGN="TOP">

  <TD NOWRAP>Shipping Method:</TD>

  <TD>Registered<BR><FONT CLASS="fv">By default, with tracking number and insured up to 30 euros only.</FONT></TD>

  </TR>





</TABLE>



</TD><TD WIDTH="40%" VALIGN="TOP">



<TABLE WIDTH="100%" BORDER="0" CELLPADDING="1" CELLSPACING="0" CLASS="ta">

 <TR>

  <TD>Order Total:</TD>

  <TD ALIGN="RIGHT">EUR&nbsp;8.92</TD>



 </TR>

 <TR>

  <TD>Shipping:</TD>

  <TD ALIGN="RIGHT">EUR&nbsp;4.85</TD>



 </TR>

 <TR>

  <TD>Insurance:</TD>

  <TD ALIGN="RIGHT">EUR&nbsp;0.00</TD>



 </TR>

 <TR>

  <TD>Additional&nbsp;Charges&nbsp;1:</TD>

  <TD ALIGN="RIGHT">EUR&nbsp;0.00</TD>



 </TR>

 <TR>

  <TD>Additional&nbsp;Charges&nbsp;2:</TD>

  <TD ALIGN="RIGHT">EUR&nbsp;0.00</TD>



 </TR>

 <TR>

  <TD>Credit:</TD>

  <TD ALIGN="RIGHT">EUR&nbsp;0.00</TD>



 </TR>



 <TR>

  <TD>Grand&nbsp;Total:</TD>

  <TD ALIGN="RIGHT"><B>EUR&nbsp;13.77</TD>



 </TR>



 <TR>

  <TD>Orders&nbsp;in&nbsp;this&nbsp;Store:</TD>

  <TD ALIGN="RIGHT">1</TD>

 </TR>



</TABLE>



</TD></TR>

</TABLE><HR NOSHADE SIZE="1" COLOR="#000000"><TABLE BORDER="0" CELLPADDING="0" CELLSPACING="0" WIDTH="100%" CLASS="ta"><TR><TD><B>Items in Order</B></TD></TR></TABLE><HR NOSHADE SIZE="1" COLOR="#000000"><TABLE WIDTH="100%" BORDER="0" CELLSPACING="1" CELLPADDING="3" CLASS="ta"><TR BGCOLOR="#C0C0C0"><TD><B>Image</B></TD><TD ALIGN="CENTER"><B>Condition</B></TD><TD><B>Item Description</B></TD><TD ALIGN="RIGHT"><B>Lots</B></TD><TD ALIGN="RIGHT"><B>Qty</B></TD><TD ALIGN="RIGHT"><B>Left</B></TD><TD ALIGN="RIGHT"><B>Price</B></TD><TD ALIGN="RIGHT"><B>Total</B></TD><TD ALIGN="RIGHT"><B>Weight</B></TD></TR><TR><TD COLSPAN="2" BGCOLOR="#C0C0C0"><B>Batch #1</B></TD><TD COLSPAN="7" BGCOLOR="#C0C0C0"><TABLE BORDER="0" CELLPADDING="0" CELLSPACING="0" WIDTH="100%"><TR><TD><FONT CLASS="fv">Submitted on Nov 20, 2013 17:12</TD><TD ALIGN="RIGHT"><A HREF="/orderDetail.asp?ID=3953198&viewItems=Y&orderBatchID=1"><IMG SRC="/images/printer16.png" WIDTH="16" HEIGHT="16" BORDER="0" ALT="Print Batch" TITLE="Print Batch"></A><IMG SRC="/images/dot.gif" WIDTH="5" HEIGHT="1"><IMG SRC="/images/invoice16YC.gif" WIDTH="16" HEIGHT="16" ALT="Batch Invoiced" TITLE="Batch Invoiced"></TD></TR></TABLE></TD></TR><TR BGCOLOR="FFFFFF"><TD HEIGHT="60"><CENTER><A ID='imgLink0' HREF='/catalogItemPic.asp?P=60208' REL='blcatimg'><IMG ALT="Lot ID: 48295541  Part No: 60208  Name: Wheel 31mm D. x 15mm Technic" TITLE="Lot ID: 48295541 Part No: 60208  Name: Wheel 31mm D. x 15mm Technic"  BORDER='0'  WIDTH='80' HEIGHT='60' SRC='http://img.bricklink.com/P/86/60208.gif' NAME='img0' ID='img0' onError="killImage('img0');"></A><BR><FONT FACE='Tahoma,Arial' SIZE='1'>*</FONT></TD><TD ALIGN="CENTER"><B>New</B></TD><TD><SPAN CLASS="u"><A HREF="/catalogItem.asp?P=60208"><FONT COLOR="#000000">Light Bluish Gray Wheel 31mm D. x 15mm Technic </FONT></A></SPAN><BR><FONT CLASS="fv">AB4</FONT></TD><TD ALIGN="RIGHT">&nbsp;</TD><TD ALIGN="RIGHT">12</TD><TD ALIGN="RIGHT">X</TD><TD ALIGN="RIGHT">EUR&nbsp;0.11</TD><TD ALIGN="RIGHT">EUR&nbsp;1.32</TD><TD ALIGN="RIGHT"><FONT CLASS="fv">38.16g</TD></TR><TR BGCOLOR="EEEEEE"><TD HEIGHT="60"><CENTER><A ID='imgLink1' HREF='/catalogItemPic.asp?P=6179' REL='blcatimg'><IMG ALT="Lot ID: 49014568  Part No: 6179  Name: Tile, Modified 4 x 4 with Studs on Edge" TITLE="Lot ID: 49014568 Part No: 6179  Name: Tile, Modified 4 x 4 with Studs on Edge"  BORDER='0'  WIDTH='80' HEIGHT='60' SRC='http://img.bricklink.com/P/86/6179.gif' NAME='img1' ID='img1' onError="killImage('img1');"></A><BR><FONT FACE='Tahoma,Arial' SIZE='1'>*</FONT></TD><TD ALIGN="CENTER"><B>New</B></TD><TD><SPAN CLASS="u"><A HREF="/catalogItem.asp?P=6179"><FONT COLOR="#000000">Light Bluish Gray Tile, Modified 4 x 4 with Studs on Edge </FONT></A></SPAN><BR><FONT CLASS="fv">AJ2</FONT></TD><TD ALIGN="RIGHT">&nbsp;</TD><TD ALIGN="RIGHT">12</TD><TD ALIGN="RIGHT">X</TD><TD ALIGN="RIGHT">EUR&nbsp;0.633</TD><TD ALIGN="RIGHT">EUR&nbsp;7.596</TD><TD ALIGN="RIGHT"><FONT CLASS="fv">23.28g</TD></TR><TR BGCOLOR="#DDDDDD"><TD COLSPAN="3"><B>Batch Total:</B></TD><TD ALIGN="RIGHT">2</TD><TD ALIGN="RIGHT">24</TD><TD></TD><TD>&nbsp;</TD><TD ALIGN="RIGHT">EUR&nbsp;8.92</TD><TD ALIGN="RIGHT"><FONT CLASS="fv">61.44g</TD></TR><TR BGCOLOR="#C0C0C0"><TD COLSPAN="3"><B>Order Total:</B></TD><TD ALIGN="RIGHT">2</TD><TD ALIGN="RIGHT">24</TD><TD></TD><TD>&nbsp;</TD><TD ALIGN="RIGHT">EUR&nbsp;8.92</TD><TD ALIGN="RIGHT"></TD></TR><TR><TD COLSPAN="10" ALIGN="RIGHT" BGCOLOR="#EEEEEE"><TABLE BORDER="0" CELLPADDING="0" CELLSPACING="0" WIDTH="100%"><TR><TD><FONT CLASS="fv">Estimated Weight of Order:</FONT></TD><TD ALIGN="RIGHT"><FONT CLASS="fv">2.17oz&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;61.44g</FONT></TD></TR></TABLE></TD></TR></TABLE><TABLE WIDTH="100%" BORDER="0" CELLPADDING="1" CELLSPACING="0" CLASS="ta"><TR><TD COLSPAN="2" CLASS="fv" ALIGN="RIGHT"><A HREF="/contact.asp?orderID=3953198">Contact your buyer about this order</A><BR>&nbsp;</TD></TR></TABLE><HR NOSHADE SIZE="1" COLOR="#000000"><FONT CLASS="fv"><CENTER>This order will be purged from the BrickLink website on May 20, 2014.</CENTER></FONT></TABLE><FONT CLASS="fv"><P><CENTER><A HREF="Javascript:window.history.go(-1)"><FONT COLOR="#FFFFFF">Back to Orders</FONT></A> | <A HREF="/orderDetail.asp?ID=3953198&viewChk=Y"><FONT COLOR="#FFFFFF">Show Temporary Checkboxes</FONT></A> | <A HREF="/orderDetail.asp?ID=3953198&viewCategory=Y"><FONT COLOR="#FFFFFF">Show Categories</FONT></A> | <A HREF="/orderDetail.asp?ID=3953198&viewGB=N"><FONT COLOR="#FFFFFF">Consolidate Batches</FONT></A> | <A HREF="/orderSettings.asp"><FONT COLOR="#FFFFFF">My Settings</FONT></A><P><A HREF="orderDetail.asp?ID=3953198&viewRemain=N"><FONT COLOR="#FFFFFF">Hide Qty Left in My Inventory</FONT></A> | <A HREF="orderDetail.asp?ID=3953198&viewWeight=N"><FONT COLOR="#FFFFFF">Hide Item Weight</FONT></A> | <A HREF="orderDetail.asp?ID=3953198&viewCost=Y"><FONT COLOR="#FFFFFF">Show My Cost</FONT></A> | <A HREF="orderDetail.asp?ID=3953198&viewItems=Y"><FONT COLOR="#FFFFFF">Show Only Items in Order</FONT></A> | <A HREF="orderEdit.asp?ID=3953198"><FONT COLOR="#FFFFFF">Edit Order</FONT></A>
```

Comment: The `font` element has been deprecated long ago.

Comment: Oh, and do I know that. It's not my website, I'm using it paying the maker a fee. The site is going to be revamped next year, as it is from the old 90's. However the question is just about pulling the data on that line on a webpage and using it to take out some data. Thanks for reading, though.

Comment: Do you have a sample web page? Does the web page indicate the shipping cost?

Comment: @duhaime I would have on my server a... say a table with the shipping costs based on weight. Now, what I needed, would be to take that bit of data from the order.com website into my own server. (On my own server process the weight data that I took, match it with the shipping cost, pull out invoices, etc). The weight data is in the order page, always on a line like the one I posted on the question. I just read about web scraping. Maybe some PHP that looks into the order page till it finds the line with the weight, and pulls out the weight? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a little tough to write full-blown code without looking at the page you wish to scrape, but you should be able to use the following code to get what you want. The code below reads in a file called "html.txt", finds all orders in that text file, finds the total weight values in ozs and grams, and writes that data to an output file called foundWeights.txt. To run the code, just save your html in a text file called "html.txt", save the code below in a file called "findweights.py", and then put both of those files in the same folder. Then, open a shell or a terminal window, navigate to that folder, and type "python findweights.py" and momentarily a text file will appear in the same folder with your data in it.

```
html = open("html.txt").read()
out = open("foundWeights.txt", "w")


#split html on order number
legoOrders = html.split("Order #")

for order in legoOrders[1:]:
  print order
  orderNumber = order.split("<")[0]

  weightString = order.split('Estimated Weight of Order:</FONT></TD><TD ALIGN="RIGHT"><FONT CLASS="fv">')[1]
  splitWeightString = weightString.split('&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;')
  splitStringFinal = splitWeightString[1].split("<")

  grams = splitStringFinal[0]
  ozs = weightString.split('&nbsp')[0]

  out.write(str(orderNumber) + "\t" + str(grams) + "\t" + str(ozs) + "\n"
```

Outfile is tab-separated (Order #, grams, ozs):

```
3953198 61.44g  2.17oz
```

Comment: To be honest, I've never worked around with Python before. To my understanding, what that does is pull out whatever is in between the first line "Estimated Weight of..." and the first "&nbsp", am I right? I'll look around in the web on saving it and using it to search a table and return a value, etc. If what I needed to pull out were the grams number (only the number) would splitString = string.split('&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp')
splitStringAgain = splitString[1].split('g</FONT>') work? Thanks once again.

Comment: Another Q: the actual string varies order to order. The order pages always have the same format and are (i. e.) order1.asp order2.asp order3.asp. How would that go into order1.asp, pull out the shipping weight, and do the same on order2 and 3.asp?

Comment: I've edited my response to show how you can extract grams. It would be easy to modify this code to read one or more webpages and then extract the ozs or grams, but I'd need the web pages...

Comment: In regards to your last question, like I said, it's hard to answer these questions in the abstract, but if you can send a hyperlink I can modify the code to do what you like

Comment: To run the code above, save it as htmlparse.py, save your html in a file called "html.txt", place them in the same folder, and then open up a shell (or terminal window), change directories until you are in that folder, and then type "python htmlparse.py" and the program will print the values. If you want to extract multiple oz values from a given page, just post the page (stripped of whatever sensitive material) and I'll be happy to modify the code accordingly.

Comment: The problem is that to access those order pages you need my or the buyer's credentials. Nothing like this has been done before, so no previous code. The order's website is not mine, but like an eBay for Lego. How could I give you more info? (PS. Maybe the TL;DR that I'm about to make will give more info) and thanks for keeping with me.

Comment: Allright, I'm getting there, thanks for the comment that you wrote while I was writing mine. Care to go into chat or too tired of me? :-)

Comment: I would, but SO says you don't have enough reputation to chat. We could google chat, if that would be helpful (I'm douglas.duhaime@gmail.com). I'll post revised code above, though--see if this solves the problem...